# Programatically interact with IVR

Tags: arduino, voice-recognition, ivr

I am about to develop application that will call IVR and make selections there, like after IVR "says" the text *"press 1 to get more info"* my application should press 1.
I have no idea how to start. Should it be something Arduino based + voice recognition? Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: This isn't a design round table.  Study something.  Also your question contains no code, so it fails the requirements of the `arduino` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a simple app for that using [Dasha](https://dasha.ai/).

Sample DSL (DashaScript) code:

```
start node root {
    do {
        #connectSafe("<PHONE_NUMBER>"); //call phone number
    }
    transitions {
        press_number: goto press_number on #messageHasAnyIntent(["press_one", "press_two"]); //use conversational AI to understand that IVR says "press 1 to get more info"
    }
}

node press_number {
    do {
        if(#messageHasIntent("press_one")) 
            #sendDTMF("1"); //make selection by sending DTMF code
        if(#messageHasIntent("press_two"))
            #sendDTMF("2");
    }
}
```

Then you can save IVR's reply using Dasha's speech recognition and pass it to your app.

If you need any help, feel free to join our [dev community](http://community.dasha.ai/) or drop me a line at vlad@dasha.ai.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

(This is just the start of the path)

You could doing it in python with : https://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm
before diving in the sources : https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject

Or if you need a bash command the sipp tool could be you're friend : https://github.com/SIPp/sipp